# how to bypass the necessity of having to have email address firstname and lastname in liferay to import authenticating users

Tags: ldap, liferay

My application uses liferay to connect to LDAP server and import authenticating users. But many of the user records in the ldap schema doesn't have email id. This seems to be preventing me from importing these users as liferay requires email id, among other things, inorder to successfully import new user records.
I am wondering if my above assertion is entirely correct. If it is, then is there a way to bypass this, so that I can import any user with `objectclass: inetOrgPerson` and has the attributes `cn` and `userPassword`

Please correct me if I am wrong in any of these, and please provide with a solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be easy to remove Liferay's dependency on users having a unique email address - it might be easier to set them up with an artificial email address in order to import them.

In case you stumble upon this artificial email address in Liferay's UI and don't like it, you can always update the UI and hide the mail address there.

Another option is to update your terms&conditions and require every user to have an email address - e.g. for contacting them in order to reset their password in case they ever forget it.

But, as the meat of your question is to remove the need for an email address per user: There's not a simple switch. I'd advise against modifying this quite central assumption. You can do it, but it won't be pretty and probably not well maintainable (just think about the various "subscribe" options all over the many components that Liferay comes with)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand it is not a good design to avoid email altogether. I found one way to add dummy email to records which doesn't have one. We can add the following lines to the "portal-ext.properties" file.     `users.email.address.required=false`
`users.email.address.auto.suffix=@no-emailaddress.com`
`users.email.address.generator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.DefaultEmailAddressGenerator` And then we can hide the field when we encounter "no-emailaddress.com"

Comment: good that you found this - I wasn't aware of this (maybe I was in the past, but not any more). Thank you for reporting the solution back.